# How to send from terminal A a command for a program open in terminal B?

Tags: linux, terminal

I have two gnome terminals open: terminal A (/dev/pts/0) and terminal B (/dev/pts/1). In terminal B, I opened gnuplot, so what I see in terminal B is

```
gnuplot>
```

and terminal B is, therefore, ready to get instructions. Let's suppose that one such instruction is "plot x", which should produce a plot of the function y(x)=x. However (and here comes the question), what I need to do is to feed gnuplot with such instruction from terminal A. What I'm looking for is something like

```
execute-command "y(x)=x" > /dev/pts/1 &
```

where execute-command is what I do not know.

I already tried with

```
exec "y(x)=x" > /dev/pts/1 &
```

but didn't work, since "y(x)=x" is not a valid command. I mean, it is valid for gnuplot, but it doesn't seem to work like this.

Comment: Writing to `/dev/pts/X` sends output to the terminal, not input. You need to write to the master end of the pty.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process

Comment: @Barmar if you also told how to open the master end of a tty given just the path to the _slave_ (or a file descriptor open to it), that would be great ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure there's any easy way. Linux uses a pty multiplexer, it doesn't put the master end in the filesystem.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492302/how-can-we-find-out-the-pseudoterminal-master-and-slave-from-each-other

Comment: also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493684/308316) for a ready-to-run demo of injecting input into a terminal via the `TIOCSTI` ioctl. Notice however that `TIOCSTI` only works from a process running as `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`/root or on the controlling tty. `TIOCSTI` is also no longer available on OpenBSD.

Comment: It might be more fruitful to think of this from the other end. On terminal A you could open gnuplot and ask it to take input from terminal B: `gnuplot < /dev/pts/1`.   This sort of works, but it leaves gnuplot fighting with whatever other input method is handling terminal B (i.e. character echo may hit gnuplot twice).